# How to construct a one-one mapping from natural numbers to irrational numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am stuck on the problem of finding a one-one mapping from natural numbers to irrational numbers. Can anyone help?

Comment: Do natural numbers include $0$?  If not, map $n$ to $n\pi$

Comment: What about $n \mapsto n+\sqrt2$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Has to include 0, unfortunately.

Comment: So map $0$ to $-\pi$

Comment: @ZiqiFan: Just pick an irrational number $\alpha$ and send $n$ to $(n+1)\alpha$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sqrt{2}$ is irrational. The map $f(n) = (n+1)\sqrt{2}$ sends distinct natural numbers to distinct irrational ones.